# CGLib no default constructor error when using spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, cglib

I am trying to use AOP for logging all method calls while entering and leaving a method, using the below bean and aop declaration in my beans xml,

```
<aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="componentAnnotatedClass" expression="execution(* com.test.*.*.*(..))" />  
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="loggingAdvisor" pointcut-ref="componentAnnotatedClass"  />
    </aop:config>
    <bean id="loggingAdvisor"  class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor">
        <property name="enterMessage" value="Entering $[targetClassShortName].$[methodName]($[arguments])" />
        <property name="exitMessage" value="Leaving $[targetClassShortName].$[methodName](): $[returnValue], Total Execution Time : $[invocationTime]ms" />
    </bean>
```

But when i use this i am getting an exception like below,

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.test.dao.BCommonDataAccessor]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
```

When i browsed through this, i got to know that cglib requries a default consructor, but in my app i have a parametrized constructor to inject my data source. I cannot have a default constructor in my data accessor. Is there any workaroud to over come this issue.
Note: I am using spring3.2 vesion

Comment: Can you inject the datasource via setter or simply autowire  ?

Comment: No I am not able to autowire the data source because I have initialized my classes which implements stored procedure in my dao constructor... In my classes I am compiling using a compile keyword... So I get a null pointer when trying to compile with the datasurce